# macOS Bluetooth menu bar show BLE Devices

Tags: macos, bluetooth

My Bluetooth menu (the one in the menu bar) do not show the Bluetooth Low Energy devices, from example my Razer mouse, it just shows up if I alt/option + click the icon.

Does anyone know how can I make the menu show all Low Energy Bluetooth devices in the menu bar?

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior.

BLE ([Bluetooth Low Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Technical_details)) devices aren't broadcasting at all times like classic Bluetooth devices, they respond to "advertising packets" sent by the scanning device (your Mac).

> BLE devices are detected through a procedure based on broadcasting
>   advertising packets. This is done using 3 separate channels
>   (frequencies), in order to reduce interference. The advertising device
>   sends a packet on at least one of these three channels, with a
>   repetition period called the advertising interval. For reducing the
>   chance of multiple consecutive collisions, a random delay of up to 10
>   milliseconds is added to each advertising interval. The scanner
>   listens to the channel for a duration called the scan window, which is
>   periodically repeated every scan interval.

When you hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while clicking on the Bluetooth icon, you're telling it to "send the advertising packets to discover the BLE devices".