# Magic keyboard and trackpad via wired connection but internal transmitter is always on and a question

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to use Magic keyboard and trackpad via wired connection.
But I've checked in the Apple store that those device's bluetooth transmitter is still on even when they are wired into mac.

I wonder if the bluetooth transmitter in those devices make high level of EMF when it is not connected to mac via wireless connection.. I have little knowledge about bluetooth . I watched some videos on youtube and found bluetooth devices emit quite high level of EMF when they are transmitting data with computer.

So anyone has ever checked the level of EMF on Magic Keyboard and Trackpad  emitting EMF alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Apple "Magic" peripherals (mouse, keyboard, track pad) are [Bluetooth 4.2 or LE](https://www.slashgear.com/new-apple-mouse-keyboard-incoming-with-bluetooth-le-14397335/) (low energy) devices which, unlike regular Bluetooth devices, [Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338323/119271) doesn't broadcast all the time.

Basically, the device will only listen for connection requests and respond accordingly.  So, when they say it's always on, it only means it's on and listening; not broadcasting.

Comment: Thank you so much Allan. Your answer is very helpful :)

Comment: How is it possible to listen without transmitting|broadcasting?

Comment: @xged - The radio in your WiFi chip is a  *transceiver* meaning it has both the ability to listen and transmit, and like any transceiver based device (walkie-talkie), it can listen without transmitting.  Transmitting (active) requires much more power than receiving (passive).