# Is there any way to spoof Bluetooth LE4.0 (low energy standard) on older Mac hardware to enable Apple Compatibility and Handoff?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, bluetooth, continuity

I have an iPhone and iPad running iOS 13 but my older Mac Mini (2010) and MacBook Air (2009) are no longer compatible with Apple Continuity or Handoff.

Everything worked fine in iOS 10 and Yosemite. At some point Apple ‘broke’ this feature for older Macs without low energy compliant Bluetooth compatibility. I’ve tried rolling everything back to before but it seems like Apple changed the ‘rules’ somehow and now this feature no longer works.

I’d like to just have the Macs broadcast or advertise or handshake (whatever the protocol requires) as if they are low energy devices. Neither Mac operates without being plugged in so I really don’t care about the energy consumption or any additional radiation since the Bluetooth is always on anyway.

Comment: It's macOS that sends the handshake, it's the adapter itself.  The adapter advertises whether or not it has BLE.  In other words, the app doesn't handle any of this - it just checks to see if there's a compliant chipset installed.  If not, the feature isn't available.

Comment: In that case it would be iOS that is seeking a BLE device?

Comment: No.  It's not the OS that seeks a BLE device.  The OS tells the BT transmitter to start advertising.  The rest is handled by the BT radio and controller.   See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338323/119271